# How to create a hashmap that contains optional and when retreiving it gives me the value or Optional.empty but there are restrictions

Tags: java, dictionary, option-type

> How to create a hashmap that contains optional and when retreiving it gives me the value or Optional.empty? However, I am not allowed to check for null, Optional.empty() or use `isPresent()`, `isEmpty()`, `get()`.

For `Optional<V> get`, `.get()` would either give me null or Optional value but what I want is `Optional.empty()` or Optional value as I would need to chain these optional together later.

For example, `.get("John").flatMap(x -> x.get("ModName")).flatMap(x -> x.get("TestName")).map(Assessment::getGrade)`.
If "John" does not exist in the first map then `.get("John")` will give me a null and if I use `.flatMap(x -> x.get("ModName"))`, I would get a null pointer exception.

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

class CustomMap<V> {
    private final Map<String, Optional<V>> map;

    public CustomMap() {
        map = new HashMap<String, Optional<V>>();
    }

    public Optional<V> get(String key) {
        return map.get(key);
    }

    public int size() {
        return map.size();
    }

    public CustomMap<V> put(V item) {
        map.put(item.getKey(), Optional.ofNullable(item));
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just do a `contains` check in `get`?

Comment: I think the purpose of the assignment is to prevent me from using any sort of checking to get true or false value but I will try to use this. Thanks.

Comment: Note that in your `put` method, you are calling `item.getKey()`, so it is impossible after that point that `item` is `null`. Therefore, you don’t need to use `Optional.ofNullable(item)` but can just use `Optional.of(item)`. But reasonable software wouldn’t store optionals into the map, but just the value, as an absent key is equivalent to an empty optional. I.e. `private final Map<String, V> map = new HashMap<>(); public CustomMap<V> put(V item) { map.put(item.getKey(), item); return this; } public Optional<V> get(String key) { return Optional.ofNullable(map.get(key)); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a check in your get method, like this:

```
public Optional<V> get(String key) {
    if (map.contains(key)) {
        return map.get(key);
    } else {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I am unable to check for null,to check for Optional.empty(), isPresent(), isEmpty(), get(). I have updated the question to reflect the to check part

Comment: If you are allowed to use the contains method of HashMap, i changed my example to use that.

Comment: Or just `map.getOrDefault(key, Optional.empty())`